# Ruby for loop prints extra things

Tags: ruby

I have an of arrays of arrays, and it looks like this:

```
[
  [[1, 3], [3, 0]],
  [[0, 0], [0, 3], [3, 2], [3, 3]],
  [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 3], [3, 1]],
  [[1, 2], [2, 2]],
  [[1, 1], [2, 1]]
]
```

I want to print each element. I expect this output:

```
0,(1,3),(3,0)
1,(0,0),(0,3),(3,2),(3,3)
2,(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,0),(2,3),(3,1)
3,(1,2),(2,2)
4,(1,1),(2,1)
```

This is my code:

```
for indx in 0..4
    print "#{indx}"
    for cell in cell_arr[indx]
        print ",(#{cell[0]},#{cell[1]})"
    end
    if indx <= 4
      puts 
    end
end
```

The output I got:

```
0,(1,3),(3,0)
1,(0,0),(0,3),(3,2),(3,3)
2,(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,0),(2,3),(3,1)
3,(1,2),(2,2)
4,(1,1),(2,1)
0..4
```

During the end of the output, my code generates something extra.

Comment: Said another way, it's not your ruby program that is printing out `0..4`, it is the environment that you're running your code in (`irb`?) that prints out the result of the whole program after the program has finished running.

Comment: How do you run your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0..4
```

is a return of **for**
If you call

```
for i in 0..100
end
```

the returns will be

```
0..100
```

to escape this:

```
for indx in 0..4
    print "#{indx}"
    for cell in cell_arr[indx]
        print ",(#{cell[0]},#{cell[1]})"
    end
    if indx <= 4
      puts 
    end
end; nil
```

Comment: Doesn't this produce `nil` instead of `0..4` at the end? ;-)

Comment: ```0..4``` may make it confusing, it may find that it belongs to the matrix ... whith return ```nil``` it will make sure it does not belong to the matrix

Answer (score 0):

Option nesting [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) inside [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
array.map.with_index { |ary, i| (ary.each_with_object ([]) { |e, tmp| tmp << "(#{e.first}, #{e.last})" }).unshift(i).join(',') }
```

Which puts:

```
# 0,(1, 3),(3, 0)
# 1,(0, 0),(0, 3),(3, 2),(3, 3)
# 2,(0, 1),(0, 2),(1, 0),(2, 0),(2, 3),(3, 1)
# 3,(1, 2),(2, 2)
# 4,(1, 1),(2, 1)
```

---

The nested loop operates on each sub-array in this way:

```
sub_arry = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 3], [3, 1]]
res = sub_arry.each_with_object ([]) { |e, tmp| tmp << "(#{e.first}, #{e.last})" }
res #=> ["(0, 1)", "(0, 2)", "(1, 0)", "(2, 0)", "(2, 3)", "(3, 1)"]
```

The idea is to place the index of the element inside the array, then use [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-join) to build the row to be printed:

```
res.unshift(2).join(',')
#=> "2,(0, 1),(0, 2),(1, 0),(2, 0),(2, 3),(3, 1)"
```

Comment: OP asked to print required output & when he print using iterators, OP gets return value which is not required. But it does return something, minimal we can return is nil. Check my answer also.